# How do I format my output when computing with arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, math, fractions

I'm writing a program that will ask the user to input the numerator and denominator of two fractions and asks for which math method to use like this:

```
System.out.printf("Numerator for the first fraction: ");
f1 [0] = input.nextInt();
System.out.printf("Denominator for the first fraction: ");
f1[1] = input.nextInt();
System.out.printf("Numerator for the second fraction: ");
f2[0] = input.nextInt();
System.out.printf("Denominator for the second fraction: ");
f2[1] = input.nextInt();
System.out.printf("Enter the operation (+, -, *, /): ");
op = input.next();
```

Assuming I wanted to add the fractions I just entered,the program stores the values in an array and passes it to this method

```
public static int[] addFractions(int[] f1, int[] f2) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    result[0] = (f1[0] * f2[1]) + (f2[0] * f1[1]);
    result[1] = f1[1] * f2[1];

    return simplifyFraction(result); //simplifyFraction is just a method that simplifies the numbers using gcd
}
```

Here is what I use to print the answer.

```
addFractions(f1,f2);
        System.out.printf("%d/%d %s %d/%d = %s",f1[0],f1[1],op,f2[0],f2[1],Arrays.toString(addFractions(f1,f2)));
```

My answer, however, looks like this:

```
1/2 + 1/2 = [1, 1]
```

What am I doing wrong? I want my output to be displayed as just "1/1". I can handle the rest of the logic to just output the numerator if the denominator is 1, I just can't format it correctly.

Comment: Why not return a string to convert [1,1] to a string containing "1/1"

Comment: `%s` -> `%d/%d`         `Arrays.toString(addFractions(f1,f2))` -> `answerArray[0], answerArray[1]`

Comment: You post nice questions for a newbie; my upvote for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as below

**Solution 1**

```
int[] answer = addFractions(f1,f2);
System.out.printf("%d/%d %s %d/%d = %d/%d", f1[0], f1[1], op, f2[0], f2[1], answer[0], answer[1]));
```

It uses the same idea that you used to print the operands.

**Solution 2 (better than solution 1)**

Alternatively, you can use a custom formatter.

```
public String formatFraction(int[] fraction){
  String result;
  if(fraction[1] == 1){
    result = String.valueOf(fraction[0]);
  }else{
    result = fraction[0] + "/" + fraction[1];
  }
  return result;
}
```

and call it on the print method

```
System.out.printf("%d/%d %s %d/%d = %s", f1[0], f1[1], op, f2[0], f2[1], formatFraction(formatFraction));
```

The `[` and `]` are printed because it is printing an array, so it prints every element of it inside `[ ]` separated by a `,`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, @VersaceVerac If it really helped, could you accept it as the answer to the question? :)

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution for representing as [1/1]

just replace

`Arrays.toString(addFractions(f1,f2))`

with

`Arrays.toString(addFractions(f1,f2)).replaceAll(", ", "/")`

for representing [1, 1] to [1/1]

Answer (score 0):

And an answer going beyond the scope of the current problem: it is of course possible to see fractions as an array of int with two entries.

But the *real* object oriented answer here: you create a **class** that represents fractions. Like:

```
public class Fraction {
  private final int numinator;
  private final int denominator;

  public Fraction(int numinator) {
    this(numinator, 1);
  }

  public Fraction(int numinator, int denominator) {
    this.numinator = numinator;
    if (denominator == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant create fraction with 0 denominator");
    this.denominator = denominator;
  }
```

and then you can implement **methods** on this class for printing, comparing, or operations such as plus(), minus(), ....